# what I want is when I press the initial letter of each name to show me the name with its initial letter

Tags: java, spring, boot

I make a simple database of names. There are a couple of names:(for example) Alexander , Anthony , Amelia , Asher and Matin. And I want to get all names that contains letter "a" but only these which have first letter "a" not Matin because a is the second letter in the word . I have in my repository this method:

```
@Query(value = "select ID, F_NAME, L_NAME FROM TEACHERS WHERE F_NAME LIKE  %:firstName% ",nativeQuery = true )
List<Teacher>findByFirstname( @Param("firstName") String firstName);
```

I created an application with a list of professors with spring and when I click on the first letter of the name, the list shows all the names that contain this letter ,

what I want is when I press the initial letter of each name to show me the name with its initial letter

Comment: remove the first `%` --> `:firstName%`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in your case you should delete the first % and make your code like this:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT ID, F_NAME, L_NAME FROM TEACHERS WHERE F_NAME LIKE :firstName%", nativeQuery = true)
List<Teacher> findByFirstname(@Param("firstName") String firstName);
```

Then, you can call the method and pass in the letter you want to search for as a parameter, like this:

```
List<Teacher> teachers = findByFirstname("a");
```

This will return a list of all teachers whose first names start with the letter "a".